# Purple vertical line, brand new iMac

Tags: imac, visual-artifacts

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRMJKM6BDhk

[image: Purple vertical line on display of iMac]

... What is this? Is my brand new three-week-old iMac dying?

The purple line shows up on anything black; images, Flash video's and so on. If I open up a black image and drag it around, the purple line stays in place. It's as if it was drawn on the screen.

I'm guessing that its the graphics card that's dying - but question is; is it hardware or software?

*If you guys know of an official Apple support ticket, or anything where Apple has recognised this problem, please share. I've got no backup computer, and I can't be without one for the obligatory 30 days it takes for Apple to sort stuff out.*

**Update:** the purple line now blinks/flickers.

Comment: I know how it is not to be able to give away the main working machine. My MacBook has had display problems since years now and they got worse and worse because I couldn't afford to have them fixed while it was still under warranty...

Comment: This is my issue. I build the Internet. Having it sent off to Apple-land for three weeks is not good.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like there's a loose connector on the LCD. I've seen that happen on my old thinkpad (they replaced the LCD panel on that) and an old display. I'm surprised that got through QA, but yes, getting it fixed when its still under warranty sounds like a VERY good idea.